# Show sites in a different language (German in my case) / Seiten auf Deutsch anzeigen

Tags: help

(rough English translation below)

Team,

leider kann ich nicht so perfekt die englische Sprache. Um nun perfekt mit dem Tor-System arbeiten zu können wollte ich fragen , wie ich alle Seiten auf deutsch umstellen kann und ob die deutschen Seiten dann immernoch sicher sind.

Danke im Voraus und würde mich freuen, wenn Ihr mir helfen könnt.

Grüße von einer User´in

---

Team

Unfortunately, my English isn't perfect. In order to be able to work with Tor, I'd like to know how I can change all the sites to German. Also, does this have any impact on security.

Thank you in advance, any help is appreciated.

Regards, a Tor user

Comment: You could use Google Translate. (Warning, joke)

Comment: Wondering about your background though. Because you're definitely not German either.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can change in which language sites is requested. Go to Preferences → Content → Choose and make sure German is on top of the list.

Concerning security, the browser will send the list of languages to any site you visit. To preserve the users privacy, Tor browser, by default, requests the sites in English, independent of the interface language. This is done to ensure the browser's fingerprint is the same for all Tor users. If you change the language, you change your fingerprint which allows to distinguish you from others Tor Browser users. I recommend you stick with English and search for a German button on the web site if necessary.

---

(German translation)

Ja, du kannst die Sprache, in welcher Webseiten angefordert werden ändern. Du kannst dies unter Preferences → Content → Choose Einstellen (auf Deutsch vermutlich Einstellungen → Inhalt → Wählen). Stell sicher das Deutsch zuoberst auf der Liste steht.

Bezüglich Sicherheit, der Browser sendet die Liste der Sprachen an jede Webseite die du besuchst. Um die Privatsphäre der Nutzer zu bewahren vordert Tor Browser der Tor Brwoser standardmäßig die englische Seite an, unabhängig von der Interfacesprache. Damit wird sichergestellt, dass der Fingerprint des Browsers aller Tor Benutzer gleich ist. Wenn du die Sprache änderst, ändert Sie auch dein Fingerprint, was es erlaubt dich von anderen Tor Browser Benutzern zu unterscheiden. Ich empfehle dir, falls möglich, weiterhin Englisch zu verwenden und nach einem Deutsch Button auf der Seite zu suchen falls es nötig ist.